# Change Sculpt Brush Strength with Scroll Wheel

Tags: customization, shortcut

Is there any way I can change the hotkeys in the Blender 2.80 settings to change the brush **strength**? I know you can change size with <kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>]</kbd>, but what about changing the strength with, say <kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>=</kbd> (i.e. the <kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>+</kbd> keys on the physcial keybaord itself).

A more ideal option would be to do this with the mouse scroll wheel while holding down a keyboard key such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, as this is obviously more comfortable to use.

I don't necessarily want to use python scripts or addons, mainly because though my Python ability is pretty good, by Blender-Python ability is 0. However, if that is the only way, I'll take it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Landed here when looking for the `F` (drag mouse to change brush radius) and `SHIFT-F` (drag mouse to change brush strength) shortcuts: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/sculpting/tool_settings/brush_settings.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to control the brush strength.